# Ajax to show data from database in table but data is save as string seperated by comma?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i want 33 and 123 of heading 1 and heading 2 to be show in new row but unable to do so plz help. 
updated but for loop is showing only last value

```
 $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"{{route('sliders.detail')}}",
      data:{slug:slug, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
      success:function(data){
        var result = data;
       // alert(result);{"heading1":"33,123","heading2":"33,123"}
        var obj = JSON.parse(result);
        //alert(obj);[object Object]
        var array1 =obj.heading1.split(",");
        var array2 =obj.heading2.split(",");
        var arrayLength=array1.length;


        if( obj!=''){
          $('#view_info').modal('show');
           for(i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){
          $('.info_data').html('<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed"><tr><th>Heading 1</th><th>Heading 2</th><tr><td >'+array1[i]+'</td><td>'+array2[i]+'</td></tr></tr></table>'); 
        }
        }
        else{
            $('#view_info').modal('show');
        }
      }
  });
```

Comment: What do you means?

Comment: what is the format of the response from the server?

Comment: It's normal, you make a `JSON.parse()`. It will decode the JSON. Here's some help https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: instead of using alert() to debug, you should use console.log() or console.dir() as it will not break runtime and show objects

Comment: it will but what to do with multi details to pass in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
$('.info_data').html(
'<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
 <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Heading 1</th>
    <th colspan="2">Heading 2</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>'+obj.heading1.split(',')[0]+'</td>
  <td>'+obj.heading1.split(',')[1]+'</td>

  <td >'+obj.heading2.split(',')[0]+'</td>
  <td>'+obj.heading2.split(',')[1]+'</td>
 </tr>
</table>');
```

If you have multi comma,and you want to loop it and display them, try this:

```js
$.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"{{route('sliders.detail')}}",
      data:{slug:slug, _token: '{{csrf_token()}}'},
      success:function(data){
        var result = data;
       // alert(result);{"heading1":"33,123","heading2":"33,123"}
        var obj = JSON.parse(result);
        //alert(obj);[object Object]
        var array1 =obj.heading1.split(",");
        var array2 =obj.heading2.split(",");
        var arrayLength1 = array1.length;
        var arrayLength2 = array2.length;

        if( obj!=''){
          $('#view_info').modal('show');
          $html = '<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
 <tr>
    <th colspan="' + arrayLength1 + '">Heading 1</th>
    <th colspan="' + arrayLength2 + '">Heading 2</th>
 </tr><tr>';
        for(i=0; i < arrayLength1; i++){ $html += '<td>'+array1[i]+'</td>'; }
        for(i=0; i < arrayLength2; i++){ $html += '<td>'+array2[i]+'</td>'; }
        $html += '</tr></table>';

        $('.info_data').html($html); 
        } else{
            $('#view_info').modal('show');
        }
      }
  });
```

Comment: i updated my question  but for loop is showing only last value of heading i.e 123 only

Comment: @kaps You cannot put `$('.info_data').html()` in your loop. It will cover your html of `.info_data`

Comment: then how can i use loop in that ajax ,i serached for it and didn't find a good solution

Comment: @kaps you need to concat the html string, I have updated my answer.

Comment: but why for loop is not working in my code ( i want to know my mistake)

Comment: @kaps Because you are setting html in loop. I am setting html out of loop, but concat html string in loop.